# Error when using rref: "Undefined function for input argument of type 'cell'."

Tags: matlab, math

Input:

```
B = {0 1 1 1 1; 0 -1 -1 1 1; 0 1 1 -1 2}
B = 

    [0]    [ 1]    [ 1]    [ 1]    [1]
    [0]    [-1]    [-1]    [ 1]    [1]
    [0]    [ 1]    [ 1]    [-1]    [2]
```

And then when i try to run the rref(B) it gives me this:

```
rref(B)

Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in rat (line 58)
    tol = 1.e-6*norm(X(isfinite(X)),1);

Error in rref (line 27)
[num, den] = rat(A);
```

Any clue why ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a little friendly advice for future posts: I made an edit to your question. If you compare the current and the previous title, you'll see that the current one is much more descriptive. "MATLAB: error with rref() and table" doesn't really say anything about the problem. Also, it's not necessary to include MATLAB in the title, as the tag alone makes the post pop up for anyone interested in answering MATLAB questions (it's possible to select favorite tags). Now, the positives: You included a reproducible code, and included the entire error message. That's *VERY GOOD!!* =)

Comment: It's interesting that `rref ` doesn't do any type checking of its own. But then again that would be unnecessary work in most cases, and the code will break sooner or later with non-matrix input (like here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input to [`rref`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rref.html) has to be a numeric array. In MATLAB, [square brackets are used to create regular matrices](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html), while [curly brackets are used for cells](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html).

So, the following works fine:

```
B = [0 1 1 1 1; 0 -1 -1 1 1; 0 1 1 -1 2];
rref(B)   
ans =

     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

If you get the `B` variable from another function, as a cell, you can use [`cell2mat`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert it to a regular matrix, and use that as input, like this:

```
rref(cell2mat(B))
```